# position: sticky only works on the right side

Tags: html, css

I would like my cell to stick to the left or right of the scrollable container. As you can see the yellow cell is only sticking to the right side despite `left: 0px`.

How can I get it to stick to both, as in if you scroll all the way to the right the cell should be stuck on the left side? Like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgukbo?file=app/main.jsx

Edit: It seems if I change `direction: ltr/rtl` on the container it sticks to one or the other but not both

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 80px 200px 200px 200px;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell sticky">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: as in if you scroll all the way to the right you should see the cell stuck on the left

Comment: it appears that Kendo managed to do it using sticky: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rgukbo?file=app/main.jsx

Comment: @dippas figured it out, just had to change grid to inline-grid

Comment: ya makes sense now that I'm thinking, good catch  ;)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working by changing `grid` to `inline-grid` ‍♂️

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 80px 200px 200px 200px;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell sticky">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
    <div class="cell">5</div>
    <div class="cell">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also add min-width:100% to make sure the element keep it's block behavior in case the content is small